# JQuery Inside An Object LIteral

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this code snippet in JS:

```
var Mylib = Mylib || function(){

    var $cart         = $('#topbar_cart_value');
    var _cartObj = {
        total: 0,
        items: 0
    };    
    /**
     * 
     * @type String|el
     */
    function render() {
        //Render the total in cart
        var str = "&euro;" + str.replace(".",",");
        $cart.html(str); <--
        // THIS IS GETTING SELECTED OK!
        console.log(document.getElementById('topbar_cart_value'));
       // THIS IS GETTING SELECTED OK!
        console.log($('#topbar_cart_value'));
       // BUT THIS IS GETTING SELECTED WITH LENGHT 0! ....
        console.log($cart);
       // ...AND THEN...
        $cart.html(str); //<--DOES NOT SET THE value
    }
return {
        init : function() {
              cacheDom();
            },
            getCartObj : getCartObj,
            setCartObj : setCartObj,  
            addToCartObj: addToCartObj,
    };
}();
Mylib.init(); 
/** ..........AFTER MANY BLOCKS OF HTML AND JS ...............**/

 $(document).ready(function() { unimanlib.init( 
            {'cart_sel':'span#topbar_cart_value'
            }); });
```

The problem is explained in the `render` function.The console for the last log is:

```
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#topbar_cart_value"]
context: document
length: 0
prevObject:m.fn.init[1]
selector:"#topbar_cart_value"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't defined any functions within your Mylib IIFE i.e. where is addToCartObj for example?

Comment: The problem is that the element selected by $cart is not getting updated. If I try to update it e.g.  with the $('span#topbar_cart_value > a').html('pippo') that's ok...

Comment: You probably executing the function before DOM is ready. Try putting `$('#topbar_cart_value > a')` in jQuery document ready `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: Why does that selector start with `span`? Does that match the element type?

Comment: What does the HTML for that element look like? You  don't really need the "span" part of your selector; "#topbar_cart_value" is enough.

Comment: Also you should declare `str` with `var`.

Comment: My next piece of advice was what @jcubic mentions above. Your code is trying to update a node that doesn't yet exist in the DOM.

Comment: edited. Nothing changes

Comment: The log isn't consistent with your code, you have a different selector there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code

```
var $cart = $('#topbar_cart_value');
```

is being called once you create a Mylib object, and I think that you're creating it before the actual html is rendered.

You should use `Mylib.init();` inside the `$(document).ready` function

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem is the DOM is not ready. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element id `#topbar_cart_value`  is unique to that element.
Also check if  tag is a direct child of `#topbar_cart_value` because it won't work if any of these are false.